# Entity Framework not updating related views after changing non-nullable fields in a table to nullable

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I need to update two fields in my table from non-nullable to nullable. I was able to update my table successfully.

However, after that, I have detected some exceptions in my app during run time. The exceptions are nullargument exceptions on my two updated columns. It seems as if the app still treats those two columns as non-nullable even though they were successfully updated to nullable in my table. The exceptions are from queries on the views joined to the modified table including the two modified columns.

Comment: Maybe someone has a better answer, but instead of fighting EF, when it gets in a bad state I usually just drop the entities from the model and re-add them and let it regenerate everything from scratch. Usually ends up taking less time than trying to coerce it into doing what you want.

Comment: Thank you. Deleting the view and re-add it back solved my problem!